# C - How to use while feof loop to solve empty input file problem?

Tags: c, c89, feof

This is an assignment and my professor only allows us to use feof function to read a file input line by line. Now i have an empty file and I got stuck in an infinite loop.

```
...
while(!feof(stdin)){
    ...
    char inputLineArray[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputLineArray);
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: "Now I have an empty file" means what? Are you trying to read an empty file? Did this create one?

Comment: Send your professor back to school. `while(fgets(inputLineArray, 1000, stdin) != NULL) { . . . }`

Comment: So how could I fix this? @user3121023

Comment: @EfiShtainer `stdin` is a predefined file which is already open. You can use any opened file, but `scanf` is reading `stdin` and `fscanf` is reading the opened file you tell it (which can be `stdin`). Whereas `fgets` always needs a file variable.

Comment: @user3121023 in which case the `%*c` is not necessary, which consumes one trailing whitespace, however the added space before `%` consumes *all* leading whitespace.

Comment: `feof` doesn't read any input, so what are you supposed to use to read?  scanf?  Try using `while(scanf(" %999[^\n]", inputLineArray) == 1) {`...