# How to transfer a char in C to an array of char?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, c89

Say I have:

```
....
char aLine;
char inputLine[1000];
scanf("%c", &aLine);
....
```

Now, I want to convert aLine into an array of char so that I can count how many characters in aLine. How can i do this?

Comment: Why transfer? `scanf("%c", aLine);` . or `scanf("%c", aLine+i);` is populating in a loop. Pretty expensive way to read a character sequence, but  whatever. And fyi, if all you're doing is counting characters, you generally don't need an array at all. just count them as you see them in a `fgetc` loop.

Comment: What does "count how many characters in aLine" mean? There's exactly 1.

Comment: OP asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392825/c-how-to-use-while-feof-loop-to-solve-empty-input-file-problem) not long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Statement `scanf("%c",...` reads in a single character, so there is actually no need to count it. If you want to "convert" a single character into a string (for which you could then apply, for example, `strlen()`), write the character at a particular position. Don't forget to terminate the string with `\0` (or `0x0`) such that string functions like `printf("%s"...` or `strlen()` work correctly:

```
char aLine;
char inputLine[1000];
scanf("%c", &aLine);
inputLine[0] = aLine;
inputLine[1] = '\0';

printf("inputLine: '%s' has length %d", inputLine, strlen(inputLine));
```

or simply read in a complete line at once:

```
char inputLine[1000];
if (fgets(inputLine,1000,stdin)) {
   printf("inputLine: '%s' has length %d", inputLine, strlen(inputLine));
}
```